# Suggested refactoring for if-statement of the following form?

Tags: c++, if-statement, refactoring, theory

I'm trying to make this as generic as possible. Let's suppose that in an if-statement, I am checking for whether some boolean expression A is true. Let's say that there are specific cases to A being true, A.a, and A.b, which are mutually exclusive. The same is true for another boolean expression B. Then, consider the following code:

```cpp
if (A) {
  if (A.a) {
    somethingSpecificToAa();
    foo();
  }
} else if (B) {
  if (B.a) {
    somethingSpecificToBa();
    foo();
  }
} else {
    foo();
}
```

In my actual code `foo()` is not a single function but multiple, long lines of code. Repeating them this many times seems smelly to me, so I assume some refactoring is in order.

Since `foo()` is executed when:

- A.a is true
- B.a is true
- Neither A nor B are true

I thought of the following:

```cpp
if (A.a) {
  somethingSpecificToAa();
} else if (B.a) {
  somethingSpecificToBa();
}

if (A.a || B.a || !(A || B)) {
  foo();
}
```

which should have the same behaviour. Is this the best way to go about it? Note that the condition in the 2nd if statement of the 2nd example ends up being extremely long in reality, which is why my code still looks like the 1st example (I hate breaking up a single `if` over several lines.) I have also thought about making a lambda that returns a `bool` that is equivalent to `A.a || B.a || !(A || B)` and plugging the lambda into the 2nd if statement instead. Alternatively, I could retain the structure of the 1st example, but replace the many lines of each `foo()` with a (`void`) lambda that does the same, although I'm not sure this resolves the smell.

Am I over-engineering at this point, thinking about lambdas? Which approach is best to maintain clean code?

EDIT: Seems I've made it *too* generic. I'm dealing with STL containers, not my own classes, and a more 'accurate' example would be:

```cpp
int shirtACleanliness = calculateCleanliness(shirtA);
if (itemsToWash.contains(shirtA)) { //itemsToWash is a std::set
  if (shirtA.cleanliness > shirtACleanliness) {
    itemsToWash.erase(shirtA);
    shirtA.cleanliness = shirtACleanliness;
    itemsToWash.insert(shirtA); //the set is ordered on cleanliness, so this re-inserts in the correct position
    doSomeOtherStuff(shirtA);
  }
} else if (itemsToDry.contains(shirtA)) { //itemsToDry is a std::vector
  if (shirtA.cleanliness > shirtACleanliness) {
    itemsToDry.erase(shirtA);
    shirtA.cleanliness = shirtACleanliness;
    itemsToWash.insert(shirtA);
    doSomeOtherStuff(shirtA);
  }
} else {
  shirtA.cleanliness = shirtACleanliness;
  itemsToWash.insert(shirtA);
  doSomeOtherStuff(shirtA);
}
//am aware aware contains() is not a method for either type
//and std::vector does not have erase() by value, this is just conceptual
```

Comment: If e.g. `A` and `B` are pointers (which means you really have `A->a` and `B->a`) then you always must check `A` and `B` first anyway.

Comment: Remember that if, for any reason, you have to use a _slightly_ different `foo()` in a branch, then you will have to create an additional `foo2()`. Instead of changing the formatting of the `if`, I would break the `foo()` into smaller, manageable functions/classes, so that each `if` sub-branch seems small enough.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They aren't pointers, just an abstract representation of what I'm trying to do. But yes, even in my actual code I should be checking `A && A.a` and `B && B.a`, never just `A.a` and `B.a`.

Comment: @Tetix `foo()` as per my code above does the same no matter when it's called; I've put all the branch-specific stuff in `somethingSpecificToAa()` and `somethingSpecificToBa()`. Unless I've misunderstood your point?

Comment: @ampharos I was just thinking ahead, just in case `foo()` becomes different for one of the scenarios in a way that `somethingspecificA/B` cannot incorporate. Then a new `foo2()` is needed etc. That's why I suggested breaking `foo()` into smaller functions/classes if possible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I had to undo your edit as it actually changed the intended behaviour! I was, however, missing a `}` so thank you for calling attention to it.

Comment: Care to share some context and what A and B are? The question looks like you already have a very specific design for A and B behind the scenes. To me it seems like you're asking for something very specific whilst maybe restructuring A and B (I'm thinking virtual functions/inheritance?) would better fit the requirements. Especially since you mentioned foo(); isn't an actual function but a bunch of lines of code.

Comment: @ZeroUltimax Of course. `A` and `B` are querying whether 2 different STL containers (a `std::vector` and a `std::set`) contain a particular element. In the inner `if`s, I then check one of that element's attributes. Are you implying it might be worth implementing subclasses?

Comment: Any solutions will rely on some assumptions about whether `somethingSpecificToAa()` or `somethingSpecificToAb()` have any effect on `A`, `B`, `A.a`, or `B.a`.    If you assume no effect (and that order of evaluation of, say, `A` versus `A.a` doesn't matter) then there are plenty of options to simplify.   Problem is, you haven't provided enough information to gauge if those assumptions are valid.

Comment: I'll drop a quick sketch of what I'm thinking in an answer, nothing as drastic after all.

Comment: @Peter they indeed do not have an effect. Order of evaluation does matter, but only in the following cases: I always need to check `A` before `A.a`, and `B` before `B.a`. It doesn't matter what order I check `A` and `B` in.

Comment: @ampharos It's not accurate to say my edit changed the behavior. The behavior before and after the edit was identical, I only edited the white space which didn't change the meaning of the code in any way. It served to highlight that the behavior of the code shown was not what was being described. It's not a problem that you changed it back once the error was fixed, I wanted to highlight the mistake and I'm glad it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your recent comment, here's a bit of pseudocode that might match your use case.

```
Element* element=nullptr;

if(vectorA.contains(X)){
   element = vectorA.get(X);
}else if(setB.contains(X)){
   element = setB.get(X);
}

if(element != nullptr && element->a){
   something(element);
}

if(element == nullptr || element->a){
    foo();
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest and easiest to understand approach so far. Sadly, unless I'm being thick, there is no distinction between whether `element` has been acquired from the set or the vector, we just know whether it's found in either. So I'm lacking the exclusive behaviour that I distinguish by `somethingExclusiveToAa()` and `somethingExclusiveToBa()`. Would using a `bool`  in the 2nd block (that we assign in the 1st block) to decide between something(element) and somethingElse(element) be bad?

Comment: I was thinking `somethingExclusiveToAa()` and `somethingExclusiveToBa()` were was just getting the element, but if that's not the case, you can remove the `if(element != nullptr && element->a){ something(element);}` and put your specifics after the `get(X);`. It seems like your specific cases are making it hard to express something more generic. At this point, I'd say we don't know enough to move forward.

Comment: I've now edited the question, adding a slightly more concrete example so that when I accept your answer, its relevance is clear without skimming through comments. I've also submitted an edit to your answer as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since there's some common code in there, why not break it out into a function? You could have something like

```
template<typename T, typename F>
bool doSomething(T const& t, F f)
{
    if (t && t.a)
    {
        f();
        foo();
    }

    return static_cast<bool>(t);
}
```

And use it like

```
if (!doSomething(A, &somethingSpecificToAa) && !doSomething(B, &somethingSpecificToBa))
{
    foo();
}
```

Comment: I really like this. Maybe I'm just being slow, but how can I, in this case, define exclusive behaviour for the functor call `f()`? It should be different whether we're looking at A or B.

Comment: Just define a public function f() in A and B and replace f(); by t.f(). That means you don't need the second parameter in the template function provided by @Some programmer dude.